# C++ Warning-- Identifier expected instead of "}"

Tags: c++, enums

I got this warning when I'm declaring one enum

```
enum Mask {
  NONE = 0,
  L = 1,
  H =2,
  U =4,
  V =8,
  D = 0X10,
  E = 0X20,
  P = 0X40,
  Q = 0X80,
};

typedef std::vector<Mask> MaskVec;
```

I think this warning comes from enum declaration. Could you please help me point out the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Your code contained an extra comma.

```
enum Mask {
  NONE = 0,
  L = 1,
  H =2,
  U =4,
  V =8,
  D = 0X10,
  E = 0X20,
  P = 0X40,
  Q = 0X80 //You placed an extra comma here
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the comma after the last member of your `enum`.